# PL/SQL function return all rows from the table when it should return a specific row

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the following plsql function and the problem it has is that it returns all the rows of the table, and the condition is very clear CODE = code. Why could this be happening?

```
FUNCTION GET_UNIT_BY_PK (code IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN CLOB
IS
    l_result CLOB;
BEGIN
    SELECT '[' || 
           '{ "CODE": "' || CODE || '", "TITLE": "' || TITLE || '", "SUBTITLE": "' || SUBTITLE || '", "DESCRIPTION": "' || DESCRIPTION || '", "KEYWORDS": "' || KEYWORDS || '", "STATUS": "' || STATUS || '" }' || 
           ']'
    INTO l_result
    FROM F_UNITS
    WHERE CODE = code;

    RETURN l_result;
END;
```

If I limit the number of rows with ROWNUM = 1, it returns the first row of the table. Why is this?

```
FUNCTION GET_UNIT_BY_PK (code IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN CLOB
IS
    l_result CLOB;
BEGIN
    SELECT '[' || 
           '{ "CODE": "' || CODE || '", "TITLE": "' || TITLE || '", "SUBTITLE": "' || SUBTITLE || '", "DESCRIPTION": "' || DESCRIPTION || '", "KEYWORDS": "' || KEYWORDS || '", "STATUS": "' || STATUS || '" }' || 
           ']'
    INTO l_result
    FROM F_UNITS
    WHERE CODE = code AND ROWNUM=1;

    RETURN l_result;
END;
```

Comment: [PL/SQL Name Resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-name-resolution.html#GUID-A551A39D-7DF8-4525-BE0F-1F46FE04ED09)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing a column to itself (remember that both SQL and PL/SQL are case-insensitive, so `CODE` and `code` are the same). It isn't even looking at your parameter. It's comparing the code column to itself, which will match all rows. You need to name your parameter/variable something different than the column name to prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the procedure argument to something other than the same name as the column (otherwise when you use `WHERE code = code` then the `code` column shadows the PL/SQL function argument and you will be matching the column to itself).

Then, if you are using Oracle 12 or later, also use the built-in JSON functions to generate the JSON rather than trying to hand-generate the code. You JSON generation will not correctly handle strings that contain characters that need to be escaped (such as new lines and double quotation marks).

```sql
FUNCTION GET_UNIT_BY_PK (i_code IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN CLOB
IS
  l_result CLOB;
BEGIN
  SELECT JSON_ARRAY(
           JSON_OBJECT(
             KEY 'CODE'        VALUE code,
             KEY 'TITLE'       VALUE title,
             KEY 'SUBTITLE'    VALUE subtitle,
             KEY 'DESCRIPTION' VALUE description,
             KEY 'KEYWORDS'    VALUE keywords,
             KEY 'STATUS'      VALUE status
             RETURNING CLOB
           )
           RETURNING CLOB
         )
  INTO   l_result
  FROM   F_UNITS
  WHERE  CODE = i_code;

  RETURN l_result;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mFW4XC98)